# How can I create multithreaded code using ThreadpoolExecutor & Callable Future

Tags: java, multithreading, csv, callable

I have an execute method which is running multiple test cases one by one, the test cases are passed in a list of Strings arrays.

I am trying to run this test cases in multi-threaded way, also writing data in CSV file in parallel.

Here is what I have done but it seems that the code is not working in a multithreaded way. I have passed nThread `2,5,7` in `newFixedThreadPool()` but it is taking the same time to execute the code.

```
private void executeTest(List<String[]> inputArray) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);//2, 5, 7
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (String[] listOfArray : inputArray) {

        Callable c2 = new Callable() {
            public ApiResponse call() {
                response = runTestCase(listOfArray);                    
                try {
                    csvWriter.writeCsv(listOfArray[0], response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return response;
            }
        };
        System.out.println("nThread :"+nThreads);
        Future<ApiResponse> result = executor.submit(c2);
        result.get();

    }
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeTaken = stop - start;
    System.out.println("Total time taken :"+timeTaken+"No of Theads :"+nThreads);

}
```

Comment: It's rather misleading that the list of arrays is called "inputArray" while the arrays themselves are called "listOfArray."

Comment: Note that adding more threads for IO may not reduce the time taken, and csvWriter needs to be threadsafe if you adjust as in my answer below.

Comment: Yes, csvWriter is Thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

The call to future `result.get(0)` blocks until the action is completed, so you are just executing the tasks one by one inside your loop - even if they are actioned on different threads by the executor service.

```
// result.get();
```

Instead remove the line above and await termination at the end so that the full number of threads in your pool may receive tasks at same time, such as:

```
// All task submitted, mark for shutdown (only call after ALL submits done)
executor.shutdown();

// Wait for the executor service to finish
// You should consider how long this should be:
if (!executor.awaitTermination(whateverTimeIsReasonable, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    throw new RuntimeException("Test failed");
```

Tests that hiding exceptions are no help for testing, changing this:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to `throw new UncheckedIOException(e);` will ensure that all errors are reported.

Comment: It's also important to call shutdown on the thread pool when you're done with it, otherwise the threads will never get cleaned up.

Comment: @DuncG How we can use CountDown latch with this code ?

Comment: Simply add `latch = new CountDownLatch(inputArray.length)` before the loop, `latch.countDown()` inside the tasks, and `latch.await()` after the loop